# JTable and Combobox. Open on right click

Tags: java, swing, combobox

I have created a table and in this table certain rows are editble with a combobox. I would like this combobox to be opened with right click and not left click. I have tried several things but I think this is my closest approach:

```
resultsTable.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void mouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {


                Point p = new Point(evt.getX(), evt.getY());
                int row = resultsTable.rowAtPoint(p);
                int column = resultsTable.columnAtPoint(p);

                if (resultsTable.getModel().isCellEditable(row, column)) {
                    if (SwingUtilities.isRightMouseButton(evt)) {
                        resultsTable.setRowSelectionInterval(row, row);
                        resultsTable.setColumnSelectionInterval(column, column);

                        resultsTable.editCellAt(row, column);   
                        StatusComboBox box = (StatusComboBox) resultsTable.getModel().getValueAt(row, column);
                        box.setVisible(true);
                        box.showPopup();
                    }
                }
            }
        });
```

However, it gives me the following error:

```
java.awt.IllegalComponentStateException: component must be showing on the screen to determine its location
at java.awt.Component.getLocationOnScreen_NoTreeLock(Component.java:2062)
at java.awt.Component.getLocationOnScreen(Component.java:2036)
at javax.swing.JPopupMenu.show(JPopupMenu.java:948)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicComboPopup.show(BasicComboPopup.java:209)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicComboBoxUI.setPopupVisible(BasicComboBoxUI.java:877)
at javax.swing.JComboBox.setPopupVisible(JComboBox.java:816)
at javax.swing.JComboBox.showPopup(JComboBox.java:801)
at org.zaproxy.zap.extension.authorisationChecker.view.AuthorisationCheckerStatusPanel$1.mouseClicked(AuthorisationCheckerStatusPanel.java:154)
at java.awt.AWTEventMulticaster.mouseClicked(AWTEventMulticaster.java:270)
at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6536)
at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3324)
at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6298)
at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2236)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4889)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2294)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4888)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4534)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4466)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2280)
at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2746)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:758)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:80)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:90)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:731)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:729)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:80)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:728)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
```

With is caused by box.showPopup();

I do not understand this error since the editCellAt does display the combobox. It does (obviously ^^) not open the combobox.

Thanks!

Comment: Please provide a short runnable example ([SSCCE](http://sscce.org)), so we can also reproduce your problem. This will help us to provide an appropriate solution for your case.

Comment: My approch could be a bit different, but what about setting/overriding the listener of the `JCombobox` to open on right click instead of setting that on the table ?

Comment: @AxelH Thing is, I have only set the celleditor to a combobox, not the renderer. So when you click on the text which is displayed in the table the combobox will not be clicked

Comment: If you can post a [mcve],  as short as possible... we could check what you have.

Comment: @AxelH im on it

Comment: @Sergiy Medvynskyy im on it

Comment: @AxelH https://drive.google.com/file/d/1AM3AntXIsRVwI70ko1qxRuYFlSJVP7Tb/view?usp=sharing this is a small project with the same problem. I have made this in eclipse. Mind I did not pay attention to how clean the code is

Comment: @SergiyMedvynskyy https://drive.google.com/file/d/1AM3AntXIsRVwI70ko1qxRuYFlSJVP7Tb/view?usp=sharing this is a small project with the same problem. I have made this in eclipse. Mind that I did not pay attention to how clean the code is

Comment: @AxelH Solution in below anser, thanks for having a look!

Comment: @SergiyMedvynskyy Solution in below answer, thanks for having a look!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to access the combobox that is being used as the editor for the cell.

Basic code would be:

```
int row = table.rowAtPoint(e.getPoint());
int column = table.columnAtPoint(e.getPoint());
table.changeSelection(row, column, false, false);
table.editCellAt(row, column);
Component c = table.getEditorComponent();

if (c instanceof JComboBox)
{
    JComboBox comboBox = (JComboBox)c;
    comboBox.showPopup();
}
```

Comment: JComboBox comboBox = (JComboBox)table.getEditorComponent(); Did the trick. Thanks, been searching all day :D